# Perform row-wise operations on a data.table for a vector-valued column

Tags: r, data.table

## EDIT:

(I apologize for the fact that my example was oversimplified, and I will try to remedy this, as well as format my more relevant example in a more convenient format for copying directly into R. In particular, there are multiple value columns, and some preceding columns with other information that does not need to be parsed.)

I am fairly new to R, and to data.table as well, so I would appreciate input on an issue I am finding. I am working with a data table where one column is a colon-separated format string that serves as a legend for values in other colon-separated columns. In order to parse it, I have to first split it into its components, and then search for the indices of the components I need to later index the value strings. Here is a simplified example of the sort of situation I might be working with

```
DT <- data.table(number=c(1:5),
                 format=c("name:age","age:name","age:name:height","height:age:name","weight:name:age"),
                 person1=c("john:30","40:bill","20:steve:100","300:70:george","140:fred:20"),
                 person2=c("jane:31","42:ivan","21:agnes:120","320:72:vivian","143:rose:22"))
```

When evaluated, we get

```
> DT
   number          format       person1       person2
1:      1        name:age       john:30       jane:31
2:      2        age:name       40:bill       42:ivan
3:      3 age:name:height  20:steve:100  21:agnes:120
4:      4 height:age:name 300:70:george 320:72:vivian
5:      5 weight:name:age   140:fred:20   143:rose:22
```

Let's say that for each person, I need to know ONLY their name and age, and don't need their height or weight; in this example, and in my actual data, every format string has fields for name and age, but possibly in different positions (the fields that I am actually looking for are usually fixed in certain columns, but I am reluctant to hard-code any indices as I am not completely familiar with the production of the data files I am working with). I would first split up the format string and then do a match() search for the names of the fields I want.

```
DT[, format.split := strsplit(format, ":")]
```

At this point, the only method I used that worked to perform the match was a vapply:

```
DT[, index.name := vapply(format.split, function (x) match('name', x), 0L)]
DT[, index.age := vapply(format.split, function (x) match('age', x), 0L)]
```

because I don't know of any other way to let R know that it should be looking at the rows in the columns individually, and not bunched together as a vector, and perform the match on the vector-valued format.split column of each row, rather than trying to match the whole column of rows. Even then, once I find the indices for each row, I have to perform another strsplit and then an mapply to parse the name-value and age-value out of each person's value-string:

```
DT[, person1.split := strsplit(person1, ':')]
DT[, person1.name := mapply(function (x,y) x[y], person1.split, index.name]
DT[, person1.age := mapply(function (x,y) x[y], person1.split, index.age]
DT[, person2.split := strsplit(person2, ':')]
DT[, person2.name := mapply(function (x,y) x[y], person2.split, index.name]
DT[, person2.age := mapply(function (x,y) x[y], person2.split, index.age]
```

(And, of course, I would do the same thing for age as well)

I am working with fairly large data sets, so I'd like my code to be as efficient as possible. Does anyone have recommendations for ways I can speed up or otherwise optimize my code?

(NOTE: I am really looking for the right approach to take, not the right *apply or *ply or Map function to use. If *(ap)ply or Map really is the right approach, I would appreciate knowing which is the most efficient or appropriate for my situation, but if there is a better way of testing for intra-row duplication, I would prefer recommendations about that to function suggestions. Suggestions are welcome, though).

## EDIT 2:

It turns out that my example was much more general than it need have been. I only need two fields, which are always going to be the first two fields in the format string, without variation. The first field is just a literal character string. The second field, however, consists of at least 2 numbers, separated by commas (ultimately, I filter out any rows with more than 2 numbers in the second field, so the possibility of more is only relevant if the filtering happens after the parsing). For each of the (3) value strings, I only need to create three columns: a character column for the first field, and two numeric columns, one for each member of the comma-separated pair in the second field. Any other fields are irrelevant. My current method, which is probably quite inefficient, is to use sub() to pattern-match on the desired fields and subfields with back-references.

```
> DT <- data.table(id=1:5,
format=c(rep("A:B:C:D:E", 5)),
person1=paste(paste0("foo",LETTERS[1:5]), paste(1:5, 10:6, sep=','), "blah", "bleh", "bluh", sep=':'),
person2=paste(paste0("bar",LETTERS[1:5]), paste(16:20, 5:1, sep=','), "blah", "bleh", "bluh", sep=':'),
person3=paste(paste0("baz",LETTERS[1:5]), paste(0:4, 12:8, sep=','), "blah", "bleh", "bluh", sep=':'))

> DT
   id    format                  person1                  person2                  person3
1:  1 A:B:C:D:E fooA:1,10:blah:bleh:bluh barA:16,5:blah:bleh:bluh bazA:0,12:blah:bleh:bluh
2:  2 A:B:C:D:E  fooB:2,9:blah:bleh:bluh barB:17,4:blah:bleh:bluh bazB:1,11:blah:bleh:bluh
3:  3 A:B:C:D:E  fooC:3,8:blah:bleh:bluh barC:18,3:blah:bleh:bluh bazC:2,10:blah:bleh:bluh
4:  4 A:B:C:D:E  fooD:4,7:blah:bleh:bluh barD:19,2:blah:bleh:bluh  bazD:3,9:blah:bleh:bluh
5:  5 A:B:C:D:E  fooE:5,6:blah:bleh:bluh barE:20,1:blah:bleh:bluh  bazE:4,8:blah:bleh:bluh
```

My code then does this:

```
DT[, `:=`(person1.A=sub("^([^:]*):.*$","\\1", person1),
          person2.A=sub("^([^:]*):.*$","\\1", person2),
          person3.A=sub("^([^:]*):.*$","\\1", person3),
          person1.B.first=sub("^[^:]*:([^:,]*),.*$","\\1", person1),
          person1.B.second=sub("^[^:]*:[^:,]*,([^:,]*)(,[^:,]*)*:.*$","\\1", person1),
          person2.B.first=sub("^[^:]*:([^:,]*),.*$","\\1", person2),
          person2.B.second=sub("^[^:]*:[^:,]*,([^:,]*)(,[^:,]*)*:.*$","\\1", person2),
          person3.B.first=sub("^[^:]*:([^:,]*),.*$","\\1", person3),
          person3.B.second=sub("^[^:]*:[^:,]*,([^:,]*)(,[^:,]*)*:.*$","\\1", person3))]
```

for the splitting, and filters by

```
DT <- DT[grepl("^[^:]*:[^:,]*,[^:,]*:.*$", person1) &
         grepl("^[^:]*:[^:,]*,[^:,]*:.*$", person2) &
         grepl("^[^:]*:[^:,]*,[^:,]*:.*$", person3) ]
```

I understand that this method is probably very inefficient, but it was the first improvement I came up with over my old approach of repeatedly applying strsplit. With the new conditions in mind, is there an even better way of doing things than melt, csplit, dcast?

## EDIT 3:

Since I only needed the first two fields, I ended up trimming all the value strings, removing those with more than two commas (i.e. more than 3 2nd-field numbers), changing the commas to colons, replacing the format string of every line with the names of the (now 3) fields, and performing the dcast(csplit(melt)) as suggested by @AnandaMahto. It seems to work well.

Comment: Is it always going to be two values separated by a colon?

Comment: @AnandaMahto this is just an example. There could potentially be differing numbers of fields and differing orders of fields.

Comment: OK. But it's generally a better idea to describe your problem in terms that might actually represent your problem :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I changed the question because the problem I had went beyond the filtering. Just wanted to give you a heads-up. I also made the example slightly more typical of what I would be working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@bskaggs has the right idea that it might just make more sense to put your data into a long form, or even a structured wide form.

I'll show you two options, but first, it's always better to share your data in a way that others can actually use it:

```
DT <- data.table(
  format = c("name:age", "name:age:height", "age:height:name",
             "height:weight:name:age", "name:age:weight:height",
             "name:age:height:weight"),
  values = c("john:30", "rene:33:183", "100:10:speck",
             "100:400:sumo:11", "james:43:120:120", 
             "plink:2:300:400"))
```

I'm also going to suggest you use [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733/).

Here's how you would easily convert this dataset into a long form:

```
cSplit(DT, c("format", "values"), ":", "long")
#     format values
#  1:   name   john
#  2:    age     30
#  3:   name   rene
#  4:    age     33
#  5: height    183
#  6:    age    100
#  7: height     10
#  8:   name  speck
#  9: height    100
# 10: weight    400
# 11:   name   sumo
# 12:    age     11
# 13:   name  james
# 14:    age     43
# 15: weight    120
# 16: height    120
# 17:   name  plink
# 18:    age      2
# 19: height    300
# 20: weight    400
```

Once the data are in a "long" form, you can convert it easily to a "wide" form using `dcast.data.table`, like this. (I've also reordered the columns using `setcolorder`, which lets you rearrange the data without copying.)

```
X <- dcast.data.table(
  cSplit(cbind(id = 1:nrow(DT), DT), 
         c("format", "values"), ":", "long"), 
  id ~ format, value.var = "values")
setcolorder(X, c("id", "name", "age", "height", "weight"))
X
#    id  name age height weight
# 1:  1  john  30     NA     NA
# 2:  2  rene  33    183     NA
# 3:  3 speck 100     10     NA
# 4:  4  sumo  11    100    400
# 5:  5 james  43    120    120
# 6:  6 plink   2    300    400
```

---

How does this fare in terms of speed?

First, a very moderate dataset:

```
DT <- rbindlist(replicate(2000, DT, FALSE))
dim(DT)
# [1] 12000     2

## @bskaggs's suggestion    
system.time(colonMelt(DT))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.27    0.00    0.27

## cSplit. It would be even faster if you already had
##   an id column and didn't need to cbind one in
system.time(cSplit(cbind(id = 1:nrow(DT), DT),
                   c("format", "values"), ":", "long"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.02    0.00    0.01 

## cSplit + dcast.data.table
system.time(dcast.data.table(
  cSplit(cbind(id = 1:nrow(DT), DT), 
         c("format", "values"), ":", "long"), 
  id ~ format, value.var = "values"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.08    0.00    0.08
```

---

### Update

For your updated problem, you can `melt` the "data.table" first, and then proceed similarly:

```
library(reshape2)

## Melting, but no reshaping -- a nice long format
cSplit(melt(DT, id.vars = c("number", "format")), 
       c("format", "value"), ":", "long")

## Try other combinations for the LHS and RHS of the 
##   formula. This seems to be what you might be after
dcast.data.table(
  cSplit(melt(DT, id.vars = c("number", "format")), 
         c("format", "value"), ":", "long"),
  number ~ variable + format, value.var = "value")
```

Comment: Sorry about shifting the goalposts on this one. I edited my question to include the code for a revised example, which more accurately reflects my situation.

Comment: If I only want certain values, such as name and age in my example, and will ultimately discard height and weight wherever they appear, is there any way of discarding them as a side effect of the dcast(csplit(melt)), or should I just null-assign the columns post-cast? Also, with the data I am working with, the dcast call defaults the aggregate function to length, whereas with the example data, it does not. Why should it do this?

Comment: @archaephyrryx, add another column before using `cSplit` to help create a unique ID (for example, make it `1:nrow(DT)`). That should take care of the `length` aggregation issue. I would also just drop the columns after casting, unless you are expecting to end up with *lots* of columns.

Comment: Sorry to do this again, but I found out new information about the data I am working with, so I made some changes.

Comment: @archaephyrryx, I'm confused. Edit 3 indicates that things have worked out. Is there still a question left unresolved?

Comment: I have more or less solved the problem, but the question is open if anyone has suggestions of more general or more efficient solutions than the one I settled for.

Comment: @archaephyrryx, OK. It might help to show the actual code you've ended up with in case others are interested in trying to improve on the efficiency of whatever you've attempted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be better served by using a tall tidy format:

```
colonMelt <- function(DT) {
  formats <- strsplit(DT$format, ":")
  rows <- rep(row.names(DT), sapply(formats, length))
  data.frame(row = rows,
             key = unlist(formats), 
             value = unlist(strsplit(DT$values, ":"))
  )
}

newDT <- colonMelt(DT)
```

The result is a format that is much easier to do search and filtering without string splitting all the time:

```
   row    key value
1    1   name  john
2    1    age    30
3    2   name  rene
4    2    age    33
5    2 height   183
6    3    age   100
7    3 height    10
8    3   name speck
```

Comment: +1. I think that this should at least get the OP half-way to where they need to be. FWIW, I've written a function called `cSplit` that [I demonstrate in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821015/1270695) that would be more efficient and more generalizable to other conditions.

Comment: colonMelt - sounds painful