# Split values of a data.table column and select the lowest number or NA if all are "NA"

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table in R:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1,2", "NA,3", "NA,NA,NA",
                        "NA,NA,NA,NA", "NA,NA", "NA,4,NA,1", "NA,NA,NA", "NA,NA"))
```

```
              x
 1:        <NA>
 2:        <NA>
 3:        <NA>
 4:        <NA>
 5:        <NA>
 6:        <NA>
 7:        <NA>
 8:         1,2
 9:        NA,3
10:    NA,NA,NA
11: NA,NA,NA,NA
12:       NA,NA
13:   NA,4,NA,1
14:    NA,NA,NA
15:       NA,NA
```

Now I would like to transfer the column to numeric with the following conditions:

- If the entry is already NA, keep it as NA
- If all entries separated by commas are "NA", the field should be NA
- If "NA" and numbers are mixed, the field should contain a single number with the lowest value
- If all entries are numbers, select the single number with the lowest value

The result should look like this:

```
     x
 1: NA
 2: NA
 3: NA
 4: NA
 5: NA
 6: NA
 7: NA
 8:  1
 9:  3
10: NA
11: NA
12: NA
13:  1
14: NA
15: NA
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813095/perform-row-wise-operations-on-a-data-table-for-a-vector-valued-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by splitting the column values on the comma, converting the resulting strings to numbers, and then applying the `min` function.

For this, I've wrote custom function like this

```
# Function to compute the desired transformation
selectMinorNA <- function(x) {
  # If the entry is already NA, keep it as NA
  if (is.na(x))
    return(NA_integer_)
  # If all entries separated by commas are "NA", the field should be NA
  # I've added inf for the purpose of extracting the min value 
  nums <- as.numeric(gsub("NA", "Inf", unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))
  # If "NA" and numbers are mixed, the field should contain a single number with the lowest value
  if (all(is.infinite(nums)))
    return(NA_integer_)
  # If all entries are numbers, select the single number with the lowest value
  return(min(nums, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Applying this function to your data frame returns this

```
dt[, x := sapply(x, selectMinorNA)]
> dt
     x
 1: NA
 2: NA
 3: NA
 4: NA
 5: NA
 6: NA
 7: NA
 8:  1
 9:  3
10: NA
11: NA
12: NA
13:  1
14: NA
15: NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution in two steps:

Step 1: cast `x`in long format and convert "NA" to `NA`:

```
dt_0 <- dt %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  separate_rows(x) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x))
```

Step 2: Filter lowest values per `rowid`, join result with `dt_0`, and slice out just the first entry per `rowid`:

```
dt_0 %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  filter(x == min(x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  bind_rows(., dt_0) %>%
  slice_head()
# A tibble: 15 × 2
# Groups:   rowid [15]
   rowid     x
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1    NA
 2     2    NA
 3     3    NA
 4     4    NA
 5     5    NA
 6     6    NA
 7     7    NA
 8     8     1
 9     9     3
10    10    NA
11    11    NA
12    12    NA
13    13     1
14    14    NA
15    15    NA
```

There are warnings; they can however be ignored